# Orbeon Forms: Replacing whitespace in form fields

Tags: xpath, replace, whitespace, orbeon

I need help with xpath expressions used in Orbeon Forms. I am passing values to a web service and need to load the result of it to a static image. So for the calculated value of it I use follow

```
concat(
    'http://192.168.25.14:8084/OrbeonRouter/rest/qr?type=1&title=',
    xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/VARASection/ctrlTitle,
    '&docID=',
    xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/VARASection/docID
)
```

I am passing form field values for title and docID parameters of my service. And I need to replace the white spaces that fall in between words (not trailing or leading spaces but spaces that falls in between title) of the `xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/VARASection/ctrlTitle` string.

I even tried `normalize-space(xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/VARASection/ctrlTitle)` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `encode-for-uri()` function for this:

```
concat(
    'http://192.168.25.14:8084/OrbeonRouter/rest/qr?type=1&title=',
    encode-for-uri(xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/VARASection/ctrlTitle),
    '&docID=',
    encode-for-uri(xxf:instance('fr-form-instance')/VARASection/docID)
)
```